# Remove calendar from Windows 10 Calendar app

Tags: windows-10, outlook.com, windows-10-calendar-app

I added my outlook.com account which has my primary calendar plus an unwanted calendar. How do I remove this calendar?

When I login to outlook.com the calendar I want to delete does not appear to exist.

How can I delete it?

Note that logging in to the Windows 8 calendar app does not show this unwanted calendar.

Comment: You should be able right click on the calendar group and simply delete it.

Comment: @Ramhound The context menu only provides color options.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't this ghost-calendar in outlook.live.com calendar view, you can always disable sync for any added to Windows app  external calendar just by unticking leading checkbox in App interface